# Return empty json on null in WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to return { } instead of null  when webApi returns a null object? 
This, to prevent my user from getting errors while parsing the response. And to make the response a valid Json Response?

I know that i could be setting it everywhere manually. That when null is the response, an empty Json object should be returned. But, is there a way to do it automaticly for every response?

Comment: If you have nothing to return, the response shouldn't be null, but 404 (Not Found).

Comment: If you are using WebApi for the purposes of building a RESTful api, then I agree with @Mark Seemann. If you are just using webApi for the url routing and don't really intend to follow REST practices then you can return whatever you want.

Comment: Indeed my project is trying to follow the REST practices, so i agree with @MarkSeemann. Please put you're comment as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @spons [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22765622/126014) :)

Comment: just send new object {} instead of null .. tried following but they are returning "{}" .. I tried this --  new object {}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are building a [RESTful](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) service, and have nothing to return from the resource, I believe that it would be more correct to return [404 (Not Found)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) than a [200 (OK)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.1) response with an empty body.

Comment: Wouldn't that get confusing?  As in, you will get a 404 if the server is down as well.  How can you tell the difference?

Comment: Does it matter? As a client, what you need to know is that there's no resource at that URL. The reason is an implementation detail.

Comment: I'm the first to confess I'm no expert, but wouldn't you want to inform the user that you can't communicate with the server if you can't?  404 would be good for a get on a single object, but if you're returning a list of objects, wouldn't {} be more correct?

Comment: @andrewjboyd Yes, for a list I would return an empty list, but that's also conceptually a different kind of resource. A list is always there, but sometimes, it can be empty. A 'singleton' resource, on the other hand, either exists or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Wrong answer, you need to return 204. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32804589/631527

Comment: Don't just say "Wrong answer" unless you are 100.000% sure. It's really confusing to people trying to find a solution. The answer is RIGHT for RESTfull services. More over, your proposed solution is kinda wrong in all but a few situations (examples do not fit in a comment though)

Comment: Re-reading this discussion, I realise that I've implicitly interpreted the question as being about GET requests. With that interpretation, I believe my answer is correct. The OP isn't specific about this, though, so my interpretation may be incorrect. If, for example, we are discussing POST requests, I'd consider 404 to be clearly incorrect if the operation succeeds.

Comment: "you will get a 404 if the server is down as well" To be precise, a 404 _is_ a server response. If the server is down, you'll get whatever internal error message your user agent/browser returns in those cases (probably a DNS related error).

Comment: This is 100% incorrect. 404 means that the target resource could not be found, and correct clients _should_ assume the operation 100% failed.

Comment: But what if some object's property have null value ? ,  I have come with a solution for `Asp.NET Web API` Response to return empty `Json` body {} while any objects have null value. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492379/2218697)

Comment: What if I am trying to `POST` or `PUT` something (let us say I switched the follow status of a user), what should I return? I find returning bool is not very understandable. I would return nothing? Or should I really return something (I do not know why)?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin You *could* return 204 (No Content), but I generally recommended against that: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/30/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-204-responses

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I recommend that you read the article that I linked to.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, Ah sorry, I did not see that. Ok so I see you are with returning bool. Thank you for the article.

Comment: I understand how this is the technically correct answer, but this is one of those times where I don't know that being a purist on something like this makes the code intuitive for most developers.  This is one time I think I'd veer off the technically perfect answer return a null or empty JSON.  Just my two cents.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a `HttpMessageHandler` to perform behaviour on all requests.  The example below is one way to do it.  Be warned though, I whipped this up very quickly and it probably has a bunch of edge case bugs, but it should give you the idea of how it can be done.

```
  public class NullJsonHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            if (response.Content == null)
            {
                response.Content = new StringContent("{}");
            } else if (response.Content is ObjectContent)
            {
                var objectContent = (ObjectContent) response.Content;
                if (objectContent.Value == null)
                {
                    response.Content = new StringContent("{}");
                }

            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

You can enable this handler by doing,

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new NullJsonHandler());
```

Comment: A great piece of code; I would still follow Mark Seemann's advice in the accepted answer and instead of returning the empty JSON object, return an HTTP 404 Not Found message.

Comment: @DavidKeaveny Sometimes a 204 would be more appropriate than a 404.  Imagine the URL `/AccidentsToday`  or `/FailedTests`

Comment: Those URIs imply the return of a collection, in which case I would be inclined to always a return an empty array with an HTTP 200.As for HTTP 204, I return 204s for succesful PUT and DELETE operations; so in my NullJsonHandler, I check the request method to make sure it is a GET.

Comment: @DavidKeaveny, I'm getting "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent". Tried 'ContinueWith' to no avail, could you shed some light.

Comment: @Samuel I'm afraid this is because someone upstream has already started writing the response body to the network.  This didn't happen in earlier versions of Web API, but then the MVC perspective of streaming response bodies took over and broke the simplicity of the response pipeline.  You will probably need a different approach.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, Funny thing is I tried in another machine and it works which amuses me. The client framework breaks without this, so i got to keep digging or look for alternatives.

Comment: @Samuel  What version of Web API are you using?  The alternative approach is to create a customized JsonFormatter.  Derive from the standard one and override one of the standard methods.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, Thanks! for now I derived OkResult and ApiController's Ok() and it works, will try to post as well. If time permits, will try to go the Formatter route. What amazes is I ended up using your JsonContent implementation from Bizcoder, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks :) ,  I used some of your idea to make `Asp.NET Web API` Response return empty `Json` body {} while any objects have null value. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492379/2218697)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Darrel Miller, I for now use this solution.

---

WebApi messes with StringContent "{}" again in some environment, so serialize through HttpContent.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sends HTTP content as JSON
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Thanks to Darrel Miller</remarks>
/// <seealso cref="http://www.bizcoder.com/returning-raw-json-content-from-asp-net-web-api"/>
public class JsonContent : HttpContent
{
    private readonly JToken jToken;

    public JsonContent(String json) { jToken = JObject.Parse(json); }

    public JsonContent(JToken value)
    {
        jToken = value;
        Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        var jw = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
        jToken.WriteTo(jw);
        jw.Flush();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = -1;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Derived from OkResult to take advantage Ok() in ApiController

```
public class OkJsonPatchResult : OkResult
{
    readonly MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue acceptJson = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");

    public OkJsonPatchResult(HttpRequestMessage request) : base(request) { }
    public OkJsonPatchResult(ApiController controller) : base(controller) { }

    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var accept = Request.Headers.Accept;
        var jsonFormat = accept.Any(h => h.Equals(acceptJson));

        if (jsonFormat)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(ExecuteResult());
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage ExecuteResult()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new JsonContent("{}"),
            RequestMessage = Request
        };
    }
}
```

Override Ok() in ApiController

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    protected override OkResult Ok()
    {
        return new OkJsonPatchResult(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better solution is using Custom Message Handler.

> A delegating handler can also skip the inner handler and directly
>   create the response.

**Custom Message Handler:**

```
public class NullJsonHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var updatedResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = null
            };

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (response.Content == null)
            {
                response.Content = new StringContent("{}");
            }

            else if (response.Content is ObjectContent)
            {

                var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (contents.Contains("null"))
                {
                    contents = contents.Replace("null", "{}");
                }

                updatedResponse.Content = new StringContent(contents,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

            }

            var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
            tsc.SetResult(updatedResponse);   
            return await tsc.Task;
        }
    }
```

**Register the Handler:**

In `Global.asax` file inside `Application_Start()` method register your Handler by adding below code.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new NullJsonHandler());
```

Now all the `Asp.NET Web API` Response which contains `null` will be replaced with empty `Json` body `{}`.

**References:**
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22764608/2218697
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers