# how to modify response in .net mvc web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

Hi i have a C# model class. This class i need to pass as json response by setting his property . one property name Product of this class have type of another product class, when there is no data for Product i am getting all inner property value as blank but instead of that i want blank json property .

For Exp My Class is

```
 public class Profile_BO
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Product product{ get; set; }


    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i am initializing this class from C# data table like below : -

```
       Profile_BO profile_BO = new Profile_BO();

            foreach (DataRow dr in result.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                profile_BO.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
                profile_BO.Username = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
            }

            Product product = new Product();

            foreach (DataRow dr1 in result.Tables[1].Rows)
            {
                product.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr1[0]);
                product.Type = Convert.ToString(dr1[1]);
            }

            profile_BO.product = product;
```

Finally when i am passing as a response to method : -

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetUserInfo(Profile_Request profile_Request)
    {
           return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, profile_BO);
}
```

And when calling on client side i am getting response json **if data is present in table**  like : -

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Username": "abc",
  "product": {
    "Id": "232",
    "Type": "34cvdcbv"
  }
}
```

But when i have **no data in product table** i am getting below : -

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Username": "abc",
  "product": {
    "Id": 0,
    "Type": ""
  }
}
```

But **if no data** **i want output** like below : -

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Username": "abc",
  "product": {}
}
```

One other question is :  -  Is it right way for binding response model from dataset ?

Comment: You are initializing you product. Even if you do not set its values, `Id` is of type `Int32` and its default value is 0. You should check if if you have products first and initialize later

Comment: If I am not initializing it's giving me "product":null, I want "product":{}

Comment: I've updated my answer with an approach to get `product : {}`

Comment: @Marco, Is it right way to bind response model from dataset ?

Comment: It is _a_ way. If it works for you, it is a right way. Usually there a multiple ways to solve a problem.

Comment: @Marco,Can you tell me best way to bind response model from dataset in this scenario

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot, since I don't know how you retrieve your data, if you sue ORMs or which. This is simply opinion based and not in scope of this question.

Comment: @NiteeshKumar , I have added a better solution using `Custom Message Handler`,  instead of using `new object();` every where in your project check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445156/2218697). May be it is useful one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem you are facing, is that you are initializing an instance of `Product` regardless of the fact, that there might be no product at all. this results, to its properties getting initialized with default values. `Int32` defaults to 0. `System.String` as a reference type is `null`.

```
Profile_BO profile_BO = new Profile_BO();

foreach (DataRow dr in result.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    profile_BO.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
    profile_BO.Username = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
}

//I am assuming you only expect one row, since oyur model uses a single Product
//and no collection of products. No need for a loop then.
if(result.Tables[1].Rows.Count == 1) { 
    Product product = new Product();
    var dr1 = result.Tables[1].Rows[0];

    product.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr1[0]);
    product.Type = Convert.ToString(dr1[1]);

    profile_BO.product = product;
}
```

This should result in the following JSON being returned:

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Username": "abc",
  "product": null
}
```

EDIT: If you really must have `product : {}`, then you need ot change your model.

```
public class Profile_BO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public object product { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Declare product as an `object`. Since all classes inherit from object, you can instantiate it as an object or Product, depending on your case:

```
if(result.Tables[1].Rows.Count == 1) { 
    Product product = new Product();
    var dr1 = result.Tables[1].Rows[0];

    product.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr1[0]);
    product.Type = Convert.ToString(dr1[1]);

    profile_BO.product = product;
}
```

Or:

```
if(result.Tables[1].Rows.Count == 0) { 
    var product = new object();    
    profile_BO.product = product;
}
```

This will then result in:

```
{"Id":1,"Username":"Foo Bar","product":{}}
```

However I strongly advise to go with the first approach, because this will make testing and modifications easier, since you keep your strongly typed approach.

Comment: Hi, I have added a better solution using `Custom Message Handler`,  instead of using `new object();` every where in your project check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445156/2218697). May be it is useful one

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer doesn't contribute to your final question. So here is my edited solution.

**A Better Solution**

May be better solution is using Custom Message Handler.

> A delegating handler can also skip the inner handler and directly
>   create the response.

**Custom Message Handler:**

```
public class NullJsonHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var updatedResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = null
            };

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if (response.Content == null)
            {
                response.Content = new StringContent("{}");
            }

            else if (response.Content is ObjectContent)
            {

                var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (contents.Contains("null"))
                {
                    contents = contents.Replace("null", "{}");
                }

                updatedResponse.Content = new StringContent(contents,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

            }

            var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
            tsc.SetResult(updatedResponse);   
            return await tsc.Task;
        }
    }
```

**Register the Handler:**

In `Global.asax` file inside `Application_Start()` method register your Handler by adding below code.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new NullJsonHandler());
```

Now all the `Asp.NET Web API` Response which contains `null` will be replaced with empty `Json` body `{}`.

**References:**

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22764608/2218697)

[2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)

Comment: Did you really just copy my answer?

Comment: No @Marco I was writing the answer based on your comments, but you have posted your answer before me :). You see there is slight difference between you and me `.Rows.Count >= 1`. If are still not happy , I will delete this.

Comment: Na, keep it. I was writing my comment before I thought this through. Sorry